# Ember Corber iOS Satus Bar Color

Tags: cordova, ember.js

Possibly very simple, but how would I change the iOS status bar in my Ember Corber project to be white. It's currently stuck on transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to install [`cordova-plugin-statusbar`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-statusbar) using `corber plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar`  It’s not Corber specific but works just fine